# check out my sql query filter method,is this safe?

Tags: java, sql

```
String searchSQLFilter(String keyword){         
    for(String filter:new String[]{"|","&","*","%",";","-","+",",","<",">"}){
        keyword=keyword.replaceAll("\\Q"+filter+"\\E", ""); 
    }
    keyword=keyword.replaceAll("'","\\\\'");
    return keyword; 
}
```

sql query:

```
select * from table where title like '%"+searchSQLFilter(keyword)+"%'
```

I want to know,`searchSQLFilter` method is safe?

btw: I know this is not good,using `PreparedStatement` is better

Comment: Might I ask why you want to do your own filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no, it isn't.

**Creating your own escaping function is a bad idea**: you won't catch all the cases. Vendor-built escaping functions have been tried and tested by millions of users, and patched where necessary.

Example: did you take character encoding into account?

Answer (score 1):

Not a final answer... a blacklist approach can only be safe at a given point in time. You're missing the complex ones like `union`. At least `'` should be included in the blacklist as well.

As you already mentioned - prepared statements are better!